# Need help converting this code TradingView Pine script from Version 2 to Version 4

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code written in `TradingView` version 2:

```
v5 = na(v5[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v5[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed

longband=RSIndex[1] > longband[1] and RSIndex > longband[1] ? max(longband[1],newlongband) : newlongband


shortband=RSIndex[1] < shortband[1] and  RSIndex < shortband[1] ? min(shortband[1],newshortband) : newshortband
```

For version 2 is working fine, but when I run it on `TradingView` version 4 I am having the following error:

```
 (line 45: Undeclared identifier `v5`;)
```

Could you help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
v5 = 0.0 // first variable declaration and initialization 
v5 := na(v5[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v5[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
```

You are trying to use a variable in its own initialization, before it is declared. This has been removed from the language since version 3, the [manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed) has more detailed instructions for migrating from version 2 -> 3 onwards.

Comment: tank you bro :))